# ¿Cómo relacionar una tabla con un id de un array de otra tabla con mongodb?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongodb, express, mongoose

Estoy haciendo un proyecto utilizando una base de datos no relacional pero no he podido resolver esta parte... Espero que alguien pueda ayudarme.

**Este es mi modelo de países**

```
const { Schema, model } = require('mongoose');

const CountryShema = Schema({

    region: {
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Regions'
    },

    countries: [{
        country: {
            type: String,
            trim: true
        }
    }]
});

module.exports = model('Countries', CountryShema);
```

La parte donde está `countries`: el país que guarde debo relacionarlo con la ciudad que corresponda.

Este es mi modelo de las ciudades:

```
const { Schema, model } = require('mongoose');

const CityShema = Schema({

    country: {
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'C'
    },

    city: [{
        type: String,
        trim: true
    }]

});

module.exports = model('Cities', CityShema);
```

¿Cómo hago para que la ciudad que esté creando esté relacionada directamente con el país, y por medio de un get que pueda acceder al id del país que le corresponde a la ciudad y no me salga todos los países?

por el metodo get lo coloco asi:

```
const locationsGetCity = async (req, res, next) => {

try {
    const location = await City.find({}).populate({
        path:'country',
        model:'Countries'
    });
    res.json(location);

} catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    next();
};
```

};

pero la respuesta es que country es null.

Comment: Puedes meter una condición al `model.find()` para que te traiga sólo las ciudades de un país que te llegue por parámetro.

Comment: los paises están dentro de un array cuando lo guardo queda así:            country:[ _id : fdfd54654gdfg, country : Argentina ].  en ciudades guardo es ese _id pero no soy capaz de mostrarlo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que la estructura de tus modelos no es la mejor, estás metiendo un arreglo al documento y debería ser un documento independiente por cada uno de ellos.

Inferiré que la región es el nodo principal que no depende de otras colecciones.

**region.model.js**

```
const { Schema, model } = require('mongoose');

const schema = Schema({

    name: {
        type: String,
        required: [ true, 'La región es importante' ]
    }

}, { collection: 'regions' });

module.exports = model( 'Region', schema );
```

**country.model.js**

```
const { Schema, model } = require('mongoose');

const schema = Schema({

    name: {
        type: String,
        required: [ true, 'El nombre del país es importante' ]
    },
    region: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Region',
        required: [ true, 'La región debe ser capturada' ]
    }

}, { collection: 'countries' });

module.exports = model( 'Country', schema );
```

Hasta este punto, cuando agregues un nuevo documento a la colección de countries, te pedirá un región, esto ayudará a mongoose a hacer un mapeo referencial.

**city.model.js**

```
const { Schema, model } = require('mongoose');

const schema = Schema({

    name: {
        type: String,
        required: [ true, 'El nombre dela ciudad es requerida' ]
    },
    country: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Country',
        required: [ true, 'La región debe ser capturada' ]
    }

}, { collection: 'cities' });

module.exports = model( 'City', schema );
```

Ahora enlazamos la ciudad con el país, entonces ya tienes un enlace de 3 sin pasar un arreglo de cosas, si no que cada documento tiene su propia estructura.

Ahora, este podría ser tu query, no tengo el ambiente para probarlo, pero te lo dejo muy cercano a lo que necesitas, no te será difícil si saltan algunos errores. Te dejo documentado

```
const cityModel = require('./models/city.model');

// Haremos una función con las bondades async/await
( async() => {

    // Controlamos los errores
    try {
        const response = await cityModel.find({})
        // Populate para traer el nombre que está haciendo referencia a country
        .populate(
            {
                path: 'country',
                select: 'name region'
            }
        )
        // Populate para traer el nombre que está haciendo referencia a region dentro de country
        .populate(
            {
                path: 'country.region',
                select: 'name'
            }
        )
        // Podemos sentenciar la consulta para pedirle que traiga los datos dependiendo de un valor
        .where(
            {
                country: 'IdDeMongo'
            }
        );
    
    console.log( response );
    // Si ocurre un error, entonces lo controlamos
    } catch( e ) {
        console.error('Ocurrió un error', e  );
    }

})();
```

Te dejo literatura de [populate()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/query.html#query_Query-populate) Así podrás comprender sobre la arquitectura de tus enlaces en MongoDB

Comment: hola... muchas gracias por tu respuesta. disculpa si te molesto pero la verdad la parte del where no la entiendo muy bien y si la coloco me saca error.                                                                               aunque me trae la ciudad con su respetivo pais .... no se como mostrar que si dos o tres ciudades pertenecen al mismo pais me muestre que si es asi y no de manera independiente.... igual me has ayudado mucho.... muchas muchas gracias!!

Comment: En el `where` es para hacer un filtro en caso que lo requieras. En la literatura que te pasé de `populate()` también está la literatura del where. Para agrupar las ciudades necesitas hacer un `aggregate` y agrupar, también viene la literatura en la [documentación.](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#aggregate_Aggregate-group)